Yaml error undefined reference 'yaml_emitter'
I am trying to install risk-ISA-SIM through pulp/ara git but I got an error that yaml is missing. Then I installed the libyaml-dev pack, and now I get an error undefined reference to 'yaml_emitter_emit' and 'yaml_scalar_event_initialize'.
I tried to install different packs, but I get the same error.

So your question is?
